# Get rows between two multiple columns range?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table.

```
create table T(
    A int, B int, C int, D int, X.... 
    primary key (A, B, C, D))
```

The table is ordered by `A, B, C, D` since they are the clustered key columns. And I have another table

```
create table Range(
    A int, B int, C int, D int, Upper bit not --  0: lower, 1: upper
    primary key (A, B, C, D))
```

The table `Range` has only two rows, which give the lower and upper bound. For example.

```
A B C D Upper
3 2 9 5 0
9 1 4 1 1
```

What's the most concise way to write a query to get all the rows between `A:3 B:2 C:9 D:5 (3295)` and `A:9 B:1 C:4 D:1 (9141)` by the natural order of `A, B, C, D`?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "between"?  Are you asking about all rows that appear in the table "between" those two rows?  Are you asking about column-by-column values (if so B = 2 for lower and B = 1 for upper doesn't make sense)?  Or something else?

Comment: For a, 3 is less then 9.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres and Oracle, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (a,b,c,d) BETWEEN (SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Range WHERE upper = 0)
                    AND (SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Range WHERE upper = 1) ;
```

There is a [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) for this feature/syntax (called row value constructors) to be added in SQL-Server but since they are still considering it for a future release of SQL Server (for 6 years now), you'll have to use some less elegant condition, like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
  JOIN 
    (SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Range WHERE upper = 0) AS rlow
      ON rlow.a = t.a AND rlow.b = t.b AND rlow.c = t.c AND rlow.d <= t.d
      OR rlow.a = t.a AND rlow.b = t.b AND rlow.c < t.c
      OR rlow.a = t.a AND rlow.b < t.b
      OR rlow.a < t.a
  JOIN 
    (SELECT a,b,c,d FROM Range WHERE upper = 1) AS rhigh
      ON rhigh.a = t.a AND rhigh.b = t.b AND rhigh.c = t.c AND rhigh.d >= t.d
      OR rhigh.a = t.a AND rhigh.b = t.b AND rhigh.c > t.c
      OR rhigh.a = t.a AND rhigh.b > t.b
      OR rhigh.a > t.a ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise, but also more obscure, way to do this than [@ypercube's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782225/297408) would be the following:

For every `T` row:

1. UNION ALL the row with the `Range` table.
2. Assign row numbers to the resulting set in the order of `A, B, C, D`.
3. Explicitly assign `2` as a row number to the `T` row and INTERSECT it with the previous result.
4. Return the row if the intersection was not empty.

Or in SQL:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT T.A, T.B, T.C, T.D, 2
  INTERSECT
  SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A, B, C, D)
  FROM (
    SELECT T.A, T.B, T.C, T.D
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B, C, D
    FROM Range
  ) AS u
);
```

The idea behind the method is that, when enumerated, the `T` row would be assigned the number 2 if it indeed sorted after the specified lower bound and before the upper one, and so intersecting with itself assigned the number 2 explicitly should return a non-empty set. If the row is out of the bounds, it will be either #1 or #3, so intersection with itself as #2 will result in an empty set (the values will match, but the row numbers not).

There's also a little catch here in that the `Upper` column determining which bound is which is not used at all and the bounds are determined automatically by how they are sorted. I realise that this may not work for you. For instance, you might want to recognise situations where the bounds are assigned incorrectly, i.e. when the lower bound actually sorts after the upper bound, and so comparing any row to such a set-up should logically result in a `false`. To address that, you probably need to make the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER expression more complex than just `A, B, C, D` or, perhaps, use an additional enumeration to account for `Upper` somehow (making the query more verbose, of course).

Apart from being not very clear, this method may also turn out not very efficient in terms of performance, which you, however, would probably need to verify for yourself. Still, the question was about finding a concise way, so here you are.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 'B'-value in the table RANGE, it looks to me like the OP wants to compare the rows as numbers, so the simplest thing would be to multiply the column values with 1000 (for the A-column), 100 (for the B-column), 10 (for the C-column) and 1 (for the D-column):

```
SELECT *  FROM T  
LEFT JOIN `RANGE` U  
ON ( U.Upper=0)  
LEFT JOIN `RANGE` L  
ON ( L.Upper=1)   
Where (T.A*1000 + T.B*100 + T.C * 10 + T.D) between (U.A*1000 + U.B*100 + U.C*10 + U.D) and (L.A*1000 + L.B*100 + L.C*10 + L.D)
```

Of course this only works when the values of A, B, C and D are smaller then 10.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *  FROM T  
LEFT JOIN `RANGE` U  
ON ( U.Upper=0)  
LEFT JOIN `RANGE` L  
ON ( L.Upper=1)   
Where T.A between U.A and L.A  
        And T.B between U.B and L.B  
        And T.C between U.C and L.C  
        And T.D between U.D and L.D
```